# > Let $V_n = [2\pi n , \infty)$. Find $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty V_n$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $V_n = [2\pi n , \infty)$. Find $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty V_n$.

It seems that this intersection just gets smaller and smaller as $n$ grows. I have that $$V_1=[2\pi, \infty) \\V_2= [4\pi, \infty) \\\vdots \\ V_{50} =[100\pi, \infty)$$ so it would seem that in the end we're only left with $\infty$, but I feel like $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty V_n = \infty$ isn't true or at least defined in any way?

Comment: Is $\infty$ a number? Is $\infty$ contained in any of the intervals?

Comment: Is $\infty$ in $[x,\infty)?$

Comment: It isn't, but is it  in $[\infty, \infty)$ which is where this is going?

Comment: Note that $\infty$ is not a set. If you were right, the correct answer would be $\{\infty\}.$ (But, as noted, you aren’t right.)

Comment: I've found this problem from a measure theory book and doesn't they include the symbol $\infty$ in measure theory? So why is it that $\{\infty \}$ cannot be tought as a set?